# Flutter app release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console

I am trying to publish an app bundle in closed testing mode but i keep getting the this error :

[image]

I also tried to upload the release apk but still same error

I tried following the **Learn more** link  at the end of the error  but the only thing it seems to be saying is to make sure there are arm64-v8a or x86_64 libraries, Opened the apk in using analyze tool in android studio and there seems to be libraries visible for arm64-v8a or x86_64

this is how the config settings look in the app level build.gradle :

```
    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.xyz.xyzapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        // Use code below for production build
        // For debug mode you need to comment above lines of code
        // Issue with 'libflutter.so'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

how can i make the app  compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your build.gradle:

```
ndk {
   abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
}
```